# How to create SQL Unique constraint by time lapse

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I have table `A` with columns `from`, `to`, `val`. I want to create unique constraint where:
Only 1 record must be in time lapse `from` - `to`. Example:
There is already 1 record `(03.12.2021 11:00:00 - 03.12.2021 15:00:00)`. Now I'm adding some records, where `TRUE` it means that can be added:

---

```
(03.12.2021 10:00:00 - 03.12.2021 10:59:00) - TRUE
```

---

```
(03.12.2021 16:00:00 - 04.12.2021 10:59:00) - TRUE
```

---

```
(03.12.2021 10:00:00 - 03.12.2021 12:00:00) - FALSE
```

---

```
(03.12.2021 12:00:00 - 03.12.2021 16:00:00) - FALSE
```

---

```
(03.12.2021 11:00:00 - 03.12.2021 14:00:00) - FALSE
```

---

Simply put it should not collide.

Comment: Your example table already shows overlapping time intervals - the first two records as one example.  Have you left out anything you could explain better?

Comment: You can do it with a trigger.

Comment: If you are using a relational database (you don't say) there's no relational constraint that can do this at the database level. You'll need to add logic to your app to check for collisions while inserting and, moreover, you'll probably need to perform partial/full locking in the table, if there are multiple threads modifying the table.

Comment: i read about trigger, but it's not about. Trigger allows you to change value of every row, inserted, doesn't it? I need insert a record only if some statement is true(the time lapse doesn't exist).

Comment: A trigger can also be used to prevent unwanted inserts/updates/deletes.